# 'Back' button is not appearing after performing push segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I', performing a basic push segue (working with nibs) and from one view controller to another table view controller, and from some reason the 'Back' button is not appearing, that normally it does appear.

This is how i'm performing the push:

```
@interface HomeViewController ()

@end

@implementation HomeViewController

- (id)init {
    self = [super initWithNibName:@"HomeViewController" bundle:nil];
    if (self) {
        // Do something
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
}

- (IBAction)goToStack:(id)sender {

    StackTableViewController *stackViewController = [[StackTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"StackTableViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:stackViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES]; in viewDidLoad Method

Comment: your navigation controller is set hidden thats why you are unable to see back button

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `StackTableViewController`, you should set `setNavigationBarHidden` to `NO`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: remember that if u hidden the navigation bar in one view another view set hidden =no,

Answer (score 0):

To make sure the navigation bar **reappears every time you navigate away** from your view controller (HomeViewController), use this:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
}
```